# HTTP Live streaming on browsers

Tags: plugins, browser, quicktime, http-live-streaming

We have some encrypted HTTP live streams which we have been using on iOS device apps. We would like to use the same streams to stream content to various browsers now. With safari it is not an issue since the quicktime plugin works fine and plays the streams. But with friefox, chrome, IE we are running into issues as to how to play these streams.

Will a quicktime plugin for these browsers (assuming it is available for all of these) be able to play the streams. Is there any other player with browser plugins which can be used to play HTTP live streams (encrypted streams) on browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any good solutions for this?

Comment: We ended up using HLS for the desktop browsers. Didn't go with HTTP Live stream.

Comment: How did you implement HLS for desktop? According to [this](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/) HLS is not supported on desktop? Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: JWPlayer has a [Flash-fallback](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430189-about-hls-streaming) for HLS on desktop, so it's supported.